# R Aggregate A Data Frame By Columns Instead of By Rows

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate the columns of this data frame by unique column name (date).  I keep getting an error.  I have tried merge_all, merge_recurse, and aggregate but can not get it to work.  I have hit an impasse that is seemingly unconquerable with my knowledge set and I can not find answers that are helping anywhere.  Is this even possible? The data frame is below:

```
    2014-02-14  2014-02-14  2014-02-14  2014-02-21  2014-06-20  2014-06-20  2014-06-20  2014-09-19  Totals
PutWing 12  -6  0   171 7   -31 0   0   -77
Ten -6  0   0   24  -19 52  0   0   -10
Eighteen    -15 0   0   73  0   -70 0   0   100
Thirty  0   0   0   -149    41  64  0   0   -463
FortyTwo    0   0   0   -91 0   121 0   0   426
ATM 44  0   0   -118    -25 -199    0   0   -134
FortyTwoC   0   0   0   -67 14  0   0   0   792
ThirtyC 0   0   0   79  0   0   0   0   -509
EighteenC   61  0   0   -57 0   -32 0   0   20
CallWing    1   0   0   -48 0   0   0   0   -28
Totals  95  -6  0   -183    17  -95 0   0   116
SlopeRisk   0   0   0   26  5   -6  0   0   -26
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sum the rows of this data frame by column name"? Show the expected output. Furthermore, you data is in a unfortunate format. You should at least transpose the data.frame.

Comment: For all of the 2014-02-14 columns, sum all of the row values for each.  So instead of 3 individual 2014-02-14 columns there would just be one column with summed values.

Comment: For the given data frame above, once manipulated, I would be looking for this:

2014-02-14 2014-02-21 4012-06-20 2014-09-19 Totals
PutWing 12
Ten -6
Eighteen-15
Thirty 0
FortyTwoC 0
ThirtyC 0
EighteenC 61
CallWing 1
Totals 89
SlopeRisk 0

Comment: To do this in Excel, I would insert column between two different dates, sum the rows individually for each similar column name into the new column, then delete the three old columns.  Basically, if there is a repeat column just add all the values of those columns of the same name, by row, together.

Comment: Fyi, I retitled and made some edits to line up closer to what you're asking for.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is in `df`:

```
df <- t(df)
rownames(df) <- substr(rownames(df), 1, 11)          # only necessary if you get funny row names from data import; if your data is as it's shown you can skip this step.
df.agg <- aggregate(df, by=list(rownames(df)), sum)
row.names(df.agg) <- df.agg[[1]]
t(df.agg[-1])
```

Produces:

```
#           Totals X2014.02.14 X2014.02.21 X2014.06.20 X2014.09.19
# PutWing      -77           6         171         -24           0
# Ten          -10          -6          24          33           0
# Eighteen     100         -15          73         -70           0
# Thirty      -463           0        -149         105           0
# FortyTwo     426           0         -91         121           0
# ATM         -134          44        -118        -224           0
# FortyTwoC    792           0         -67          14           0
# ThirtyC     -509           0          79           0           0
# EighteenC     20          61         -57         -32           0
# CallWing     -28           1         -48           0           0
# Totals       116          89        -183         -78           0
# SlopeRisk    -26           0          26          -1           0
```

Basically, you need to transpose your data to use all the `group/apply` functions that R offers.  After transposing, you could also use `plyr`, `data.table`, or `dplyr` to do the aggregation instead of `aggregate` as I did, but those are all non-base packages.

This will need some cleaning up column names, etc, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: @user3311286, to the extent this answers your question, please consider marking the question as answered.  If this does not work, please follow up with comments here.